# Collision Detection and isGrounded checks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I'm currently working on a project in Unity and as I'm fairly new to C# and programming in general I'm having a few issues. The first issue is with the collision detection for my player - I have a modelled Rigidbody with gravity and a mesh collider on (non convex) attached. For my walls, they're models imported with box colliders attached.

If I keep my box colliders the default size of the model (about twice as thick as the player) then the player can glitch through it sometimes and fly out the other side. To get around this I simply make the collider bigger for the walls / environment but this is not ideal if I want the player to be able to walk around or be on both sides of the wall. Currently the player "climbs" up the side of the wall when it collides, which should not happen? I was wondering if I have something configured wrong or if it would be better to manage collision for the player entirely through script? I have a screenshot of both my character and player components below:
Wall - http://i.imgur.com/YRdTgSh.png?
Player - http://i.imgur.com/DVKOdG1.png?

My second issue is when I try to check whether my player is grounded in order to let them jump or not. The code below is my current entire movement script for managing the player moving and jumping. At the moment, the player can jump infinitely high however if I spawn the player from a high space they will only jump once, until they reach a certain height which they will then jump again from repeated until space is let go.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate() {

    // Creating floats to hold the speed of the plater
    float playerSpeedHorizontal = 4f * Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float playerSpeedVertical = 4f * Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

    // Transform statements to move the player by the playerSpeed amount.
    transform.Translate (Vector3.forward * playerSpeedVertical * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.Translate (Vector3.right * playerSpeedHorizontal * Time.deltaTime);

    // Calling the playerJump function when the jump key is pressed
    if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
    {
        playerJump();
        Debug.Log ("Can jump");
    }

}

/// Here we handle anything to do with the jump, including the raycast, any animations, and the force setting it's self.
void playerJump() {

    const float JumpForce = 1.0f;
    Debug.Log ("Should Jump");

    if(Physics.Raycast(rigidbody.position, Vector3.up, collider.bounds.extents.y + 0.1f)) {
    //  Debug.Log ("Can jump");
        rigidbody.AddForce (Vector3.up * JumpForce, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
}
}
```

If anyone could help I'd be very appreciative as I'm getting quite confused by this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When moving physics bodies, use rigidbody's AddForce function. You have used it with your jump code which is good, but you must also use it with all other movement code.

```
transform.Translate (Vector3.forward * playerSpeedVertical * Time.deltaTime);
transform.Translate (Vector3.right * playerSpeedHorizontal * Time.deltaTime);
```

Should be

```
rigidBody.AddForce(transform.forward * playerSpeedVertical);
rigidBody.AddForce(transform.right * playerSpeedHorizontal);
```

This will allow the physics engine to properly resolve the rigidbody's movement during the physics simulation. I've omitted the ForceMode parameter, but feel free to use it as you see fit.

By using transform.Translate, you were essentially teleporting the rigidbody into your collision geometry, because transform.Translate knows nothing about the physics simulation.

Also note, do not use Time.deltaTime in a FixedUpdate function, instead use Time.fixedDeltaTime. However, because the physics simulation is always calculated at a fixed rate, you never actually need to use fixedDeltaTime when applying forces.

As for the jumping, you are ray casting up. You want to ray cast down.

```
Vector3 rayOrigin = transform.position;
rayOrigin.y += collider.bounds.extents.y; //move the ray origin up into the collider, so there's no chance your ray cast will begin inside the ground
float rayDistance = collider.bounds.extents.y + 0.1f;

Ray ray = new Ray();
ray.origin = rayOrigin;
ray.direction = Vector3.down;

if(Physics.Raycast(ray, rayDistance, 1 << 8)) {
    rigidbody.AddForce (Vector3.up * JumpForce, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
}
```

Please note the third parameter of the ray cast, it is 1 << 8. This is the ray's layerMask. It will only cast against objects in this layer (so that **excludes** your player, which is why I believe you were getting incorrect raycast results before)

In order to know what parameter this should be for you, first you need to make a new layer (in Unity: Edit -> Project Settings -> Tags & Layers)

Create a layer, call it ground, or terrain. Note the layer number. (i.e. User Layer 8 would mean your third parameter for the raycast would be 1 << 8, but if you were to create the ground/terrain layer as layer 10 instead you'd use 1 << 10)

Now the final step is to assign this layer to your ground/terrain colliders.

Now your player should be casting a ray downwards, that starts at his mid section and goes a bit below his feet. This ray will ignore his colliders and only tell you when the ray is colliding with a ground layered object.

Comment: Using rigidbody.addforce for the movement doesn't let me move the player at all. Nor am I able to jump if I set it to be vector3.down

Comment: For the AddForce thing, maybe it is best you use the ForceMode.VelocityChange, as a force of 4 * playerSpeedHorizontal might not be enough to move your current rigidbody.

As for the Raycast thing, I tested it myself in unity and have noticed that there are a few things extra you will need to do in order to get the Raycast to behave nicely. I will edit my answer with my solution, check back soon.

Comment: Okay great! The jump works perfectly now! (Thank you very much) When I move my player though, he shoots off super fast in a direction but the controls act more like compass points than direction. So if I press W then he shoots off in the same direction, no matter where I'm looking. If I press S he shoots off in the opposite direction to W, no matter where I'm looking.
Could you possibly explain / comment the raycast code so I can understand what it does if possible please?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were making a platformer for some reason. Use rigidbody.AddRelativeForce, rather than rigidbody.AddForce. AddForce adds to the players velocity using the world as the reference point. So AddForce(Vector3.right * speed) will always move you along the world's positive x axis. If you use AddRelativeForce, it will add to the players velocity from the player's perspective. So AddRelativeForce(Vector3.right * speed) will move to the player's right. Also, if your player is moving too fast, reduce the speed variable that gets multiplied with Vector3.forward and Vector3.right.

Comment: I don't mean to be more of an issue but the directional bit works now however it adds velocity meaning that each time it will make the player faster and not just change it by a set amount each time.

Comment: Lol. Go back to using AddForce, but change one parameter. rigidbody.AddForce(transform.right * horizontalSpeed) note transform.right isntead of Vector3.right. I apologize for all this error correcting. And also change rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward, forwardSpeed).

Comment: Uhhmm that makes the player not move again. :/ Sorry!

Comment: Did you keep ForceMode.VelocityChange? Sorry, I keep forgetting important details. rigidbody.AddForce(transform.right * playerSpeedHorizontal, ForceMode.VelocityChange), rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * playerSpeedVertical, ForceMode.VelocityChange)

Comment: Okay so he's moving again, but he still gets faster as he moves?

Comment: I'm not sure how simulation-safe modifying the rigidbody.velocity is, but try added a new variable called playerMaxSpeed and then remove both rigidbody.AddForce() calls then in its place use this code:

`Vector3 velocity = transform.forward * playerSpeedVertical + transform.right * playerSpeedHorizontal;
velocity.Normalize();
velocity *= playerMaxSpeed;
rigidbody.velocity = velocity;`

Comment: From what I've been told and researched, directly modifying the velocity of the rigidbody is a bad thing to do. Is there no other work-around?

Comment: After a bit of a search, it's not a good idea simply due to the fact that it produces unrealistic physical effects (such as objects instantly stopping/starting their movements). The general consensus, however, is that in the case of a first person controller, no one expects realistic acceleration while controlling their character. So it's ok to directly set its velocity because the collisions are still resolved properly in the simulation.

Comment: Okay, sorry about this by the way I don't mean to make you work so hard but I do appreciate it. The player moves and such now, but it does it in segments if that makes sense? So if I press forward, it'll move a set amount each time and so if I let go it will continue with that segment of movement and then stop

Comment: Gahhh... he also does not jump properly now? I don't know what I've done :(

Comment: Oh. There you go, there is a problem with modifying velocity directly. Whenever you jump, the rigidbody's jump velocity is getting maxed out in the update loop (velocity *= playerMaxSpeed). I could think of a few work arounds but they'll all probably have problems down the line... try same code with 2 extra lines `velocity = transform.forward * playerSpeedVertical + transform.right * playerSpeedHorizontal; velocity.Normalize(); velocity *= playerMaxSpeed;
float velZ rigidbody.velocity.z; rigidbody.velocity = velocity; rigidbody.velocity.z = velZ;`

Comment: the float velZ rigidbody.velocity.z; line is causing issues for me?

Comment: `Vector3 velocity = transform.forward * playerSpeedVertical + transform.right * playerSpeedHorizontal;
  velocity.Normalize();
  velocity *= playerMaxSpeed;
  velocity.z = rigidbody.velocity.z;
  rigidbody.velocity = velocity;`

Comment: Sigh. I meant `velocity.y`... I'm trying to preserve the rigidbody's jump velocity, which is `velocity.y`, not `velocity.z`.

Comment: Ok wow, it works! Thank you so much! Sorry for the difficulty that I might've made it but I appreciate you sticking to help me. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, one last point is how it so they don't cling and climb to the wall when colliding? Sorry

Comment: Ah dammit... I make the collision boxes back to being the same size as the model and the player now glitches into them still... This so difficult. Is the velocity effecting this as I'm a little confused whether it works for a rigidbody player character controller

Comment: Really? That is just so werid... What scale are you at? For example, create a cube in unity (in the menu bar at the top, GameObject > 3D Object > Cube), they are one meter in dimensions. If your objects are around that scale, the physics should be practically flawless.

Comment: Oh, I've re-read your main post, and see you are using a mesh collider? Generally, for the purpose of character movement, you should use a capsule collider. This capsule collider is the collider used to move your character around the world. If you want to use more detailed colliders (for example so you can detect where you characters/enemies are getting shot in an FPS) you can add more colliders later. But for now, the collider that you move around the world and interacts with the walls and ground and what not should just be a single capsule collider.

Comment: I thought only one collider could be applied to a rigidbody at a time? I've added the capsule collider though and it seems to work. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Finally! Glad we got it sorted out. As for the multiple colliders thing: your other colliders won't be attached to your rigidbody game object, they'll be attached to your mesh's transforms/bones, so that the arm/leg/head/body colliders will move and rotate with the mesh properly. Those colliders won't even have rigid bodies on them. They'll just be there to be ray casted against, so you can know where your character/enemies have been shot with finer detail.

Comment: Ah right, that makes sense. Awesome! Thank you very much man, really do appreciate it

Comment: Gahhh I realised I still had an issue man, I'm ever so sorry! The player movement has a delay from releasing, it'll continue moving for a short second and then stop. Any idea? Sorry again

Comment: I actually notice this too, but because my character is in a 2d platformer, he slides to stop rather than instantly stopping, so it doesn't bother me yet, and I haven't tried to solve it. It could be because FixedUpdate happens less often than Update (by default), so there will be times where your character won't immediately stop because FixedUpdate hasn't happened yet but new frames have been rendered. Try Edit > Project Settings > Time, this will bring up TimeManager, set FixedTimestep to 0.01, rather than 0.02. See if that helps. If it doesn't, I wouldn't have any other ideas sorry :\

Comment: Okay well thank you anyway. As one last request, would you possibly mind going back to your original answer and adding in comments explaining how it works so that I can have a better understanding? Thanks again

Comment: Hi @Michael I'm not sure if you're still around but I was hoping you might be able to help with my jump once again? I've converted the project into Unity 5 now and it seems the player is no longer able to jump. I've tried rewriting the script for it but that doesn't seem to help. If you'd be able to help me, I'd be greatly appreciative once more.

Comment: To get physics components now, you must get them manually. In any script you use rigidbody, you now need to first get the rigidbody through GetComponent<Rigidbody>()